# Image of the exponential map on the 2-Sphere at a point

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Take the north pole of the standard 2-sphere in $\mathbb{R^3}$ equipped with the riemannian metric induced by the standard metric on $ \mathbb{R^3}$. What is the image of the exponential map of the tangent space at the north pole? I am having trouble with the definition of the exponential map making it hard for me to compute this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: All you need to know is the geodesics passing through the north pole are the intersections of the sphere with 2-dimensional linear subspaces that contain the north pole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sketch of the answer: all the geodesics going through the north poles are big circles,  i.e. all lines of longitude on earth.

If your tangent vector is $(x,y)=(\rho_* \cos\theta_*,\rho_*\sin\theta_*)$, then the big circle it induces is $\theta=\theta_*$ (polar coordinate, $\phi\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$). The geodesic distance from the north pole along this arc, is the angle $\pi/2-\phi$.

An exponential map maps the vector to travel the same distance along the geodesic as the vector norm in tangent space. Thus the target point is $(\theta_*,\pi/2-\rho)$.

So your exponential map $Exp: (\rho_* \cos\theta_*,\rho_*\sin\theta_*)\mapsto (\theta_*,\pi/2-\rho)$ (2d euclidean coordinates to 3d polar coordinates.)

Answer (score 6):

In the hope a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: The exponential map of the unit sphere]

Answer (score 1):

Let $p\in S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and complete an orthonormal basis $\{p,v_1,v_2\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$. In terms of this basis

let $X(\theta,\phi)=(\cos\theta, \sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta \sin\phi)=\cos\theta \cdot p+\sin\theta (\cos\phi \cdot v_1+\sin\phi \cdot v_2) $.

Then

$X(0,\phi)=p \quad|X_\theta(\theta,\phi)|=1 \quad X_{\theta \theta}(\theta,\phi)=-X(\theta,\phi)\equiv 0$ in $T_{X(\theta,\phi)}S^2$ .

Fix $\phi_0$. Then the curve $\gamma_{p,\phi_0}(\theta)=X(\theta, \phi_0)$ is a unit speed geodesic with $\gamma_{p,\phi_0}(0)=p$ and

$\gamma_{p,\phi_0}'(0)=(\cos\phi_0 \cdot v_1+\sin\phi_0 \cdot v_2)$.

But $w=(\cos\phi_0 \cdot v_1+\sin\phi_0 \cdot v_2)$ is an arbitrary unit length tangent vector in $T_pS^2.$ Therefore, we may parameterize our geodesic by unit tangent vectors in $T_pS^2$.

Let $\gamma_{p,w}(\theta)=\cos\theta\cdot p+\sin\theta \cdot w $.

As geodesics are invariant under reparameterization of the form $\theta\rightarrow \alpha \theta+\beta$ we may consider the curve

$\gamma_{p,w}(\alpha \theta)=\gamma_{p,\alpha w}( \theta)=\cos(\alpha\theta)\cdot p+ \sin(\alpha\theta)\cdot w\quad \alpha> 0$.

Then

$\gamma_{p,\alpha w}'(0)=\alpha \gamma_{p,w}'(0)=\alpha w$.

Let's rewrite $\gamma_{p,\alpha w}$ in terms of $r=\alpha w$. Notice $|r|=\alpha$ and $\frac{1}{|r|}r=w$

$\gamma_{p,r}(\theta)= \cos(|r|\theta)\cdot p+ \sin(|r|\theta)\cdot \frac{1}{|r|}r$

Therefore, we have a geodesic emanating from each point $p$ in the direction corresponding to any tangent vector $r$. Then

$\exp_p(\theta r)= \gamma_{p,r}(\theta)= \cos(|r|\theta)\cdot p+ \sin(|r|\theta)\cdot \frac{1}{|r|}r$